# Convert nested class to "raw" json

Tags: json, angular

I have the following class:

```
export class Son 
{
    public Field8_1 : number;
    public Field8_2 : number;
}

export class Father
{
    constructor (){
        this.Field8 = new Son;
    }
    public Field1 : number;
    public Field2 : number;
    public Field3 : number;
    public Field4 : number;
    public Field5 : number;
    public Field6 : number;
    public Field7 : number;

    Field8 : Son;
}
```

I have to send it with Angular's HttpClient. 
So I ran:

```
var body = JSON.stringify(this.Father);
    this.http.post (TGT_IP,body).subscribe (...)
```

The body I got is:

```
{"Field8":{"Field8_1":81,"Field8_2":82},"Field1":1,"Field2":2,"Field3":3,"Field4":4,"Field5":5,"Field6":6,"Field7":7}
```

How can I "customize" stringify to create a string according to my needs:

```
"Field1":1,"Field2":2,"Field3":3,"Field4":4,"Field5":5,"Field6":6,"Field7","Field8_1":81, "Field8_2":82
```

I want to send a "raw" string.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that in a couple of ways. Option one is to map all the keys of a father using the spread operator and of the son, and then remove the field you don't need:

```
// First option
let mappedFather1 = {
  ...this.father,
  Field8_1: this.father.Field8.Field8_1,
  Field8_2: this.father.Field8.Field8_2
};
delete mappedFather1.Field8;
```

Another option is to essentially "cherry-pick" the object keys you need:

```
// Second option
let mappedFather2 = {
  Field1: this.father.Field1,
  Field2: this.father.Field2,
  Field3: this.father.Field3,
  Field4: this.father.Field4,
  Field5: this.father.Field5,
  Field6: this.father.Field6,
  Field7: this.father.Field7,
  Field8_1: this.father.Field8.Field8_1,
  Field8_2: this.father.Field8.Field8_2
}
```

If you don't need the opening and closing braces of the JSON, you can remove them like this:

```
let noBracesFather = JSON.stringify(mappedFather1).substr(1).slice(0, -1);
```

Here is a stackblitz that logs the output to console for both options, plus removing the braces: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5wmz4c

This obviously assumes that the structure of Son and Father objects is known and that they are static.